# How to integrate Ethereum support into CoinSpace?

Tags: ether, dapp-development

CoinSpace is a fork of the Hive Bitcoin Wallet and is in active development at [github](https://github.com/orgs/CoinSpace/). I'm am interested in adding Ethereum to the wallet in the same way Litecoin is supported.

I'm looking for any resources that our developers can go to with questions.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum SE. Could you add some more details to your question, e.g., what is the status of CoinSpace, which programming language requirements are there? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

I imagine that you are referring to Hive Web Wallet (hive-js), that is a lite (web) wallet, and it doesn't do SPV like the OSX one does (via BitcoinKit).

To build a lite wallet (web wallet in ethereum terms) I suggest to start with [eth-lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) to create a **web wallet to create keys and sign transactions** that connects to a public ethereum node or a node you are hosting yourself (with geth for example), and the node doesn't have accounts or funds you use in the web wallet app, **it just relays transactions** to it.

You will also need the [hooked-web3-provider](https://github.com/ConsenSys/hooked-web3-provider) or a similar solution to relay transaction you signed with eth-lightwallet to the ethereum node. Also to strenghten the solution you could connect to multiple servers so if one goes down your wallet still works, it's still not as strong as SPV but as there are no SPV JS solution yet for ethereum, that may be a good solution.

See the [full example on eth-lightwallet repo](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet/blob/master/example/webwallet.html)

To run it, clone/download the repo, run npm install, drop the html file from the examples dir in your browser and it should work by default. I tried it with the geth host it connects to by default (104.236.65.136) and it works, if it doesn't, replace it with a public host or your own geth address (probably localhost).

Comment: Do you know who provides `104.236.65.136` @makevoid?

Comment: I think somebody from Consensys, but I can recommend signing up and using Infura (also managed by consensys) which is a good solution (hosted load balanced ethereum RPC) if you don't want to run geth/parity yourself